# Cocos2dx build issue

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x-3.x

I have latest version of Cocos2dx which is v3.12 and latest ndk r12b on Mac OSx El Captain.
I tried countless times to build my project for the android platform and I'm keep on gettting a "realocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL" error.
And the libraries don't end up linking.
How do I fix this error? Do I need maybe a previous version of cocos2dx or ndk?

Please Help.

Here is the whole error message:

```
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCNode.cpp:903: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/Android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/regex.h:2109: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/Android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/regex.h:2109: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/Android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/regex.h:515: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/Android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/regex.h:515: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libMyGame.so
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./platform/CCGLView.cpp:44: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/CCAffineTransform.cpp:73: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/CCAffineTransform.cpp:74: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Mat4.cpp:968: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Mat4.cpp:974: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Quaternion.cpp:26: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Vec4.cpp:306: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Vec4.cpp:307: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Vec4.cpp:308: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Vec4.cpp:309: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Vec4.cpp:310: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./math/Vec4.cpp:311: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCGLProgramState.cpp:46: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTextureCache.cpp:634: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCFrameBuffer.cpp:36: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCCamera.cpp:42: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/Android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/iostream:74: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/external/bullet/LinearMath/btQuickprof.cpp:21: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/external/bullet/LinearMath/btQuickprof.cpp:433: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/external/bullet/BulletDynamics/ConstraintSolver/btConeTwistConstraint.cpp:623: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/toolchain/gcc/gcc-4.9/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_globals.cc:117: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/arm-linux-androideabi/bits/gthr-default.h:778: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/ext/concurrence.h:219: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/ext/atomicity.h:49: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/ext/atomicity.h:49: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/ext/atomicity.h:49: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/toolchain/gcc/gcc-4.9/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/system_error.cc:65: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/toolchain/gcc/gcc-4.9/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/system_error.cc:66: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/ext/atomicity.h:49: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Volumes/Android/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r12-release/out/build/tmp/build-65800/build-gnustl/static-armeabij4.9/include/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:33: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:33: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:33: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:33: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:34: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:34: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:34: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:34: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCValue.cpp:36: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:63: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:63: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:64: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:64: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:65: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:65: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:66: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:66: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:67: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:67: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:68: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:68: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:69: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:69: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:70: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:70: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:71: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:71: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:74: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:74: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:75: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:75: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:76: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:76: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:77: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:77: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:81: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:81: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:85: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:85: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:97: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:97: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:102: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:102: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:107: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:107: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCTexture2D.cpp:116: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontAtlasCache.cpp:36: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontAtlasCache.cpp:36: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontAtlasCache.cpp:36: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontAtlasCache.cpp:36: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontFreeType.cpp:50: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontFreeType.cpp:50: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontFreeType.cpp:50: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCFontFreeType.cpp:50: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
/Users/moshe/developer/CrossPlatformDev/com.game.mathymaddy/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCVertexAttribBinding.cpp:46: error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_CALL
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: There's some info here to check out http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/failed-android-build-error-relocation-overflow-in-r-arm-thm-call/17932/8

Comment: I already checked that out, nothing works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try NDK r11c:

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11c-darwin-x86_64.zip

Also make sure you have the following line in your Android.mk:

`LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm`

That worked for me (and I also had the same errors with NDK r12b).  Hope this helps!

Comment: and what cocos2d-x version?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in NDKr12 when you use

> APP_ABI := armeabi

in your **aplication.mk** file. [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/16033) is the issue that opened in github of cocos2d project and [here](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/152) is the issue that opend by cocos2d-x developer on github of NDK project.
But, How about the solution? You can change your **APP_ABI** from **armeabi** to **armeabi-v7a** and compile your project without mentioned error.

Comment: This is still a bug in NDKr14b.